# How to configuring Ubuntu 10.04 server for multiple gateways in a simple way

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, nic

I have a simple Ubuntu 10.04 server that runs a service.  The system has two NIC cards each configured for separate networks.  Each NIC needs a separate gateway, but when both are configured, eth1 gets kicked off.

How else, other than specifying a gatway for each interface in /etc/network/interfaces can I configure a gateway for each NIC card?

Answer (score 1):

You need two routing tables for that, and two rules (`ip rule`) to choose the right table. (Or one primary and one extra for the other interface).

If you look [here](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html), the first example (4.2.1. Split access) is exactly what you need to configure.